# Thread 28: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) in xcode 13

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

I have an app developed in Ionic capacitor

here I attached my snapshots when run my project, It shows on exception like Thread 28: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0), I don't no how to solve this issue ...can anyone help me??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scimB.png)

Comment: Please, whats the Ionic versions and the plugins or external library are you using in your App? Could you write down or list here to better understandings where can be the fails. Thanks!

Comment: I have used version 6.0.4 of ionic(capacitor V 3.3.4) in my app, and it has image upload and image download functionality and also use firebase when i upload or download image i got this error. i tired i don't know how it solve...

Comment: Check your Angular Fire version, and you may follow a tutorial about how to upload/download an image to Firebase. The errors shows something related to `userInfouserInfo` check it also... Good luck bro!

Comment: how to resolve userInfouserInfo  issue..